# Packing Angular 2 app into JAR using Maven

Tags: maven, angular, pom.xml

I have a Front-End application built with Angular2 + Webpack with the following structure:

```
> app
    > config
    > dist
    > dll
    > node_modules
    > src
    pom.xml
    package.json
    ... (other files)
```

And I'm currently trying to use Maven to package everything generated by the application in `dist` (css, html, js) into a `.jar`.

I've filled most of my `pom.xml` file with some of the required tags like, license, developers, scm, groupId, artifactId, etc. What I'm currently having trouble with and would love some help with is the build part of the `pom.xml` where I imagine an execution or configuration should go that handles the packaging specifics like directories, but this is what I'm not too sure about, any help is greatly appreciated!

P.S. Is it possible to switch out the `dist` directory for `META-INF/resources/webjars/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something like this or I misunderstood you?

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>dist</directory>
            <targetPath>dist</targetPath>
        </resource>

        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```